# PyDev doesn't know what type array contains

Tags: python, arrays, pydev

Hello I started Python after doing java for 1 year, and it's a very hard moment learning after java, because in python everything is different OO wise, well I did PHP for 2 years before Java so PHP and Python OO wise are pretty similar.

I have this script I made so far, these two classes:

```
import random

class Questions(object):

    questions = [Questions.Question("Is Jony mad?", False),
                 Questions.Question("Is Jony happy?", True)]

    currentQuestion = None;

    def __init__(self):
        pass


    def generateQuestion(self):
        self.currentQuestion = self.questions[random.randint(0, len(self.questions))]

    def answerQuestion(self, answer):
        if (answer == self.questions[0].

class Question:

    question = None
    answer = None

    def __init__(self, question, answer):
        self.question = question
        self.answer = answer

    def getQuestion(self):
        return self.question

    def getAnswer(self):
        return self.answer
```

They are in a file named `Questions`.

I have the array questions, which should contain objects of `Questions.Question` (`Question` class).

Everything is fine until I reach this line in the method `answerQuestion`

```
def answerQuestion(self, answer):
    if (answer == self.questions[0].
```

When I do `self.questions[0].` PyDev gives no suggestions of what methods that object contains, but when I do `self.currentQuestion.` I get suggestions, but NOT from the Question class, but instead I get the methods of the array e.g `count(value)`, `remove(index)`, etc

I assume this happens because Eclipse PyDev doesn't know what type is the `questions` array.

In PHPStorm IDE I usually did `/** @var Object **/` but I am new to Python, I am not really sure how things work there.

Is there something wrong I am doing?

Comment: The Python language is too dynamic to make assumptions about what is contained in a list. You as a developer may have the intention to only have `Question` objects in that list, but PyDev cannot make that assumption.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PyDev cannot make assumptions about what a Python list contains; you can store anything in a list, including the list itself.

You *can* make an assertion; if you do, then PyDev knows enough about the type because the assertion would otherwise fail:

```
def answerQuestion(self, answer):
    question = self.questions[0]
    assert isinstance(question, Question)
    if answer == question.  # now auto-completion will work
```

It looks as if this only works with assertions on direct references, not with `self.questions[0]`.

You can also use a [Sphinx or Epydoc style type assertion in a comment](http://pydev.org/manual_adv_type_hints.html):

```
def answerQuestion(self, answer):
    question = self.questions[0]  #: :type question Question
    if answer == question.  # now auto-completion will work
```

Comment: I just tried that, seems like nothing has changed when I add the dot, nothing comes up

Comment: @BenBeri: Right, I don't actually use PyDev myself. It may be you need to first do `question = self.questions[0]` then `assert isinstance(question, Question)` after which `if answer == question.` will autocomplete.

Comment: Actually, you don't need to use the assert, you can use type-hinting with comments: http://pydev.org/manual_adv_type_hints.html

Comment: You're welcome... unfortunately PyDev still doesn't work with typing containers -- such as list(int) -- because it doesn't cope with that structure in the type-inference, but eventually it'll get to do that :)

Comment: @FabioZadrozny: Right. I'm not a PyDev user myself; I just inferred from experience with other tools that the possibility existed, then Googled. :-)